# mysqlimport keeps missing rows

Tags: mysql, csv, mysqlimport

I'm using mysqlimport to ingest a csv file.

This is the command that I used:

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --columns=$COLUMNS  --lines-terminated-by="\n" \
        --verbose --local --fields-enclosed-by='"' --host=$HOST --port=$PORT \
        --user=$USERNAME --password=$PASSWORD ${DATABASE} $FILE_PATH
```

Before I started the process, I truncated the table and it does not have any unique indexes.

The source file has 7288362 records(At beginning I thought the csv rows may contain new line characters. I did a check but there was no quoted new line characters in the fileds).

However when mysqlimport was done, it said "Records: 7288300  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 43730142".

When I logged into mysql and did a select count(*) from MyTable, it also gave me 7288300.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that you get about 6 warnings per row is a red flag. You may be loading strings that are too long for the fields, or the file has invalid date strings, or something like that. I'd make a copy of just the first line from your file and try to import it into a copy of your table. Then look at the line and the data in the table and see what the difference is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Actually I found it is caused by this kind of lines -- 1345235,62,"Theme From \Shaft\""""",,Chris Davis & Kim Waters,,,,,,5,0,,,,,,,,,,2016-10-28,,,,2016-10-28,,Y,,,,,,0,2016-10-28 09:09:39. As you can see, there are multiple double quotes and it is not escaped properly, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this kind of rows in my csv files:

```
1345235,62,"Theme From \Shaft\""""",,Chris Davis & Kim Waters,,,,,,5,0,,,,,,,,,,2016-10-28,,,,2016-10-28,,Y,,,,,,0,‌​2016-10-28 09:09:39
```

The multi quotes there caused a problem. When I added `--fields-escaped-by=''`, it worked.

Comment: Except that you probably have extra \ and " characters in your database now. I suggest you fix your CSV data file formatting before importing it.

Comment: I'm new to mysql but the source I used to build the CSV file is 
Theme From \Shaft\"", and the value in MySQL is Theme From \Shaft\"". They look the same.

Comment: Then if that's what you want in your database, it's all good.